# Writing the iterated expectation with a single integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, conditional-expectation, iterated-integrals

I would like to write the expected value of $c(x)$ where $x$ is sampled from a distribution $\gamma(x|m)$ and $m$ is sampled from another distribution $\omega(m)$. Here, for any fixed $m$, the distribution $\gamma(x | m)$ is a probability distribution supported on $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, the distribution $\omega$ is a probability distribution over some (for simplicity) interval $M$.

By the law of total expectation, we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[c(x)]  =  \int_{m \in M} \Big[\underbrace{\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} c(x) \mathrm{d} \gamma(x | m)}_{\mathbb{E}[c(x) | f]} \Big] \mathrm{d}\omega(m).$$

**I would like to take the $\mathrm{d}\gamma(x | m)$ term outside**, however, this is not easy since $m$ defines $\gamma( \cdot | m)$.

I am applying the following steps, and I am not sure where exactly I am failing since each step looks intuitive but the final expression is counter-intuitive:

\begin{align}
& \int_{m \in M} \Big[\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} c(x) \mathrm{d} \gamma(x | m)\Big] \mathrm{d}\omega(m) \tag{1}\\
= & \int_{m \in M} \Big[\int_{(m',x) \in M \times \mathbb{R}} \chi_{\{ m = m' \}} c(x) \mathrm{d} \gamma(x | m')\Big] \mathrm{d}\omega(m) \tag{2}\\
= & \int_{(m',x) \in M \times \mathbb{R}}  c(x)  \Big[\underbrace{\int_{m \in M}  \chi_{\{ m = m' \}} \mathrm{d}\omega(m)}_{\displaystyle \omega(\{m'\}) ?????} \Big] \mathrm{d} \gamma(x | m'), \tag{3}
\end{align}
where $\chi$ is the indicator. If this is true, what if $\omega(\{ m' \}) = 0$ everywhere? If this is not true, where am I failing and how can I fix this? Apologies for my lack of measure theory knowledge.

Note: in a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4311014/535163), user Masacroso told me this is related to the disintegration theorem. Here I am creating a new question since, *(i)* I think the question for total expectation generalizes my earlier question, *(ii)* I am not sure if disintegration is really what I am looking for.

Comment: you cannot move the term $\mathrm{d}\gamma (x|m)$ outside because it depends on $m$. However you can try to see if the measure define by $\mathrm{d}\nu(x,m):= \mathrm{d}\gamma (x|m)\mathrm{d}\omega (x)$ can be disintegrated in the order of integration that you want, something like $\mathrm{d}\nu (x,m)=\mathrm{d}\alpha (m|x)\mathrm{d}\beta (x)$. However I dont know so much about if this could be possible, this is why I've given just a brief comment about the disintegration theorem in the other question